# Rails' migrations in PHP

Tags: ruby-on-rails, migration, rake

Would it be possible to lift Rails' migrations and stick it straight into a PHP app (and run it with the rake command, etc)?

I've been looking into PHP equivalents, but I haven't been completely satisfied with them, so I figured there should be a way to pull Rails' version and stick it somewhere in the file structure of my app.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could certainly write a tiny little rails app that only had migrations in it - the migrations don't care what ends up using the tables they create. With a bit more work you should be able to craft something that only uses the activerecord and activesupport gem, without requiring a whole rails app.

Comment: OK, so I did end up just taking a Rails app and stripping it down to its bare essential, required set for just the migration tool.  It contains 14 directories, 14 files.  I would definitely be interested in slimming it down further to, as you say, use only those two gems.  Unfortunately I don't have the time, but I may in the future.  Maybe I'll start a github for it or something so that someone else with time could do it and send a Pull Request...